# Whats the difference between the two approaches?

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I have this question in my assignment, and the solution states that we must have two pointing indices one at the start and one at the last element and we can progress from last element to the middle and respectively the first element to the middle. However, my solution was to have one index at the middle and another at last, and the last index will just move until the middle while the middle index will move until it reaches the start. But i am confused with what's wrong with my solution

Question:

> Two stacks of positive integers are needed: one containing elements with values less than or equal to 1000 and the other containing elements with values larger than 1000. The total number of elements in the small-value stack and the large-value stack combined is never more than 500 at any time, but we cannot predict how many will be in each stack. (Initially both will be empty; later on the stacks could be evenly divided, or all the elements could be in the small-value stack, and so on.) For efficiency reasons, we want to implement both stacks using a single array of size 500. Can you think of a way to do this

Comment: I'm struggling to see the actual question here, can you clarify what the program should do?

Comment: My first reaction is "stacks don't have random access", but then the assignment specifically says to use arrays, which don't have this limitation. It's possible it's underspecified. Either way, the person to ask about this assignment is _your teacher_, not randomers on the internet.

Comment: I would also add from the end and the beginning, requiring two indices (strange assignment though...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the number 10 (less than 1000) and 400 numbers from 2001 to 2400 (greater than 1000) and try to put them on the two stacks. You will see that the solution with pointers on the two ends will work. But the solution with one pointer in the middle will not work, one of the stacks will be too small or the small value will be overwritten.